# Terminate the SSL at an apache instead of ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, ssl, amazon-elb

I want to migrate my platoform built with PHP/APACHE to AWS Cloud.
My application serves multiple website with different domains and SSL Certificates.
I can use only 50 certificate with AWS Application Load Balancer ( this is the hard limit ), so I am planning a different solution.

Can I use the Network Load Balancer and forward port 443 to my ECS instance ( Fargate ) without attaching a certificate and then terminate the SSL on apache instead of ELB?

In this way I can bypass the certificate limit and manage it with virtual host.

I'm right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you launch the network load balancer with a TCP connection based target group on port 443, then TLS termination will not occur on the load balancer.

This will forward the traffic on port 443 to your host, which if you're listening for a HTTPS connection on this port will use the terminate the TLS on the host.

Otherwise if you had a TLS target group it would terminate at the network load balancer, but then would re-encrypt between the load balancer and the host.

Comment: Thanks Chris, with Application Load Balancer is not possible because it works with layer 7, right?

Comment: Yes with ALB it will terminate TLS or HTTPS before it is forwarded to you host :)